# Java swing hold buttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to create a subclass of JButton or AbstractButton that would call specified .actionPerformed as long as the mouse is held down on the button.

So far I was thinking of extending JButton, adding a mouse listener on creation (inside constructor) and calling actionPerformed while the mouse is down. So far i came up with that but I was wondwering if I was on the right track and if so, how to correctly implement the "held down" logic.

```
package components;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class HoldButton extends JButton {

    private class HeldDownMouseListener implements MouseListener {

        private boolean mouseIsHeldDown;

        private HoldButton button;

        private long millis;

        public HeldDownMouseListener(HoldButton button, long millis) {
            this.button = button;
            this.millis = millis;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            mouseIsHeldDown = true;
//          This should be run in a sub thread?
//          while (mouseIsHeldDown) {
//              button.fireActionPerformed(new ActionEvent(button, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "heldDown"));
//              try {
//                  Thread.sleep(millis);
//              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//                  continue;
//              }
//          }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            mouseIsHeldDown = false;
        }

    }

    public HoldButton() {
        addHeldDownMouseListener();
    }

    public HoldButton(Icon icon) {
        super(icon);
        addHeldDownMouseListener();
    }

    public HoldButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        addHeldDownMouseListener();
    }

    public HoldButton(Action a) {
        super(a);
        addHeldDownMouseListener();
    }

    private void addHeldDownMouseListener() {
        addMouseListener(new HeldDownMouseListener(this, 300));
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

edit: Choosing the Timer method I came up with a working implementation:

```
package components;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class HoldButton extends JButton {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final long CLICK_LAG = 300;

    public static final long INITIAL_FIRE_DELAY = 500;

    public static final double FIRE_DELAY_STEP_MULTIPLIER = 25;

    public static final long MIN_FIRE_DELAY = 100;

    private class HeldDownMouseListener implements MouseListener {

        private class HeldDownCheckerTask extends TimerTask {

            private HeldDownMouseListener listener;

            public HeldDownCheckerTask(HeldDownMouseListener listener) {
                this.listener = listener;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                long delay = INITIAL_FIRE_DELAY;

                while (listener.isMouseHeldDownOnButton()) {
                    listener.fireMouseHeldDown();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(delay);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (delay > MIN_FIRE_DELAY) {
                        final long decrease = Math.round(FIRE_DELAY_STEP_MULTIPLIER * Math.pow(INITIAL_FIRE_DELAY / delay, 2));
                        delay = Math.max(delay - decrease, MIN_FIRE_DELAY);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private boolean mouseIsHeldDown;

        private boolean mouseIsOnButton;

        private HoldButton button;

        private Timer timer;

        public HeldDownMouseListener(HoldButton button) {
            this.button = button;
        }

        public boolean isMouseHeldDownOnButton() {
            return mouseIsHeldDown && mouseIsOnButton;
        }

        private void cancelTimer() {
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }
        }

        private void fireMouseHeldDown() {
            button.fireActionPerformed(new ActionEvent(button, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "heldDown"));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            cancelTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            mouseIsOnButton = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            mouseIsOnButton = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            cancelTimer();
            mouseIsHeldDown = true;
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new HeldDownCheckerTask(this), CLICK_LAG);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            mouseIsHeldDown = false;
        }

    }

    public HoldButton() {
        addHeldDownMouseListener();
    }

    public HoldButton(Icon icon) {
        super(icon);
        addHeldDownMouseListener();
    }

    public HoldButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        addHeldDownMouseListener();
    }

    public HoldButton(Action a) {
        super(a);
        addHeldDownMouseListener();
    }

    private void addHeldDownMouseListener() {
        addMouseListener(new HeldDownMouseListener(this));
    }

}
```

Comment: Well I think you should use javax.swing.Timer rather than java.util.Timer. And you should set it as a repetitive time (so you don't have to call sleep() yourself).

The advantage of javax.swing.Timer is that it will always run your task inside the Event Dispatch Thread, which is normally expected for any call to any Swing EventListener.

Your current implementation calls actionPerformed _outside_ the EDT which can be bad if actionPerformed() accesses or changes a GUI component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the mouse is pressed you could start a timer that invokes your action repeatedly at the interval you need until the button is let go. Then you can stop the timer. By submitting it to a timer, you can submit it to a new thread and not do the thread management yourself.

Answer (score 1):

At least one good practice is to do the 'work', in this case you actionPerformed-loop in a runnable via the SwingUtilies.invokeLater(). That way it gets offloaded to the event threadpool/queue and you're not blocking the awt main thread so you're not blocking your GUI.